# Como alternar layots no aps.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Sou iniciante em programação e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no qual já tenho as views necessárias dentro do layout base:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando o usuário clicar no botão de cadastro todo este layout deverá ser alterado para tela de cadastro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz a aplicação pelo MVC, mas como falei, sou iniciante, então tenho colocado tudo dentro da View Home e no HomeController:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da aplicação que desenvolvi até o momento:

```
using DevAnimeWeb.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DevAnimeWeb.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Anime()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Cadastro()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Calendario()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus, consequatur saepe quas vitae cum autem maxime nostrum sequi sed alias laboriosam. Suscipit, fugit dolorem tempora facilis similique quae sint ullam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi facere impedit illum, fugiat corporis porro voluptates libero maiores, labore veritatis ducimus atque nostrum, aspernatur deleniti ex non amet perferendis rerum!";

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult FilmeOva()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Generos()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult LightNovel()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Manga()
    {            
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Sobre()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "A DevAnime foi desenvolvida entre os final de 2021 e ano de 2022, com o intuito de agregar aos usuários a possibilidades de poderem ter acesso aos animes, filmes e OVA's com qualidade FullHD, além de poder dar entretenimento a todos os usuários queremos levar a condição de possiveis premiações e promoções de produtos específicos e particulares da nossa equipe, levando mais além o que nenhum outro site de animes fez.";

        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
  }
}
```

O problema é que quando clico no botão CADASTRO a tela ainda fica com o layout base e desconforme de como deveria realmente ser:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso estar aplicando para que o layout seja todo alterado para o que realmente está sendo proposto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc pode alterar o layout de uma determinada view apontando para um layout vazio ou com outros componentes que desejar.

Coloque no inicio da View

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/OutroLaytout.cshtml"; }
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!